# Find the sum of eigenvalues range of an inverse of a positive definite correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I came across this problem from an exercise book.

Suppose $P$ is a positive definite correlation matrix with inverse $P^{-1}$. Find the range of

sum of eigenvalues of $P^{-1}$.

> Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You can use the spectral decomposition to find the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}$.